Is it possible to recover deleted memos from Samsung Galaxy S7?
I partially broke my Samsung Galaxy S7, so I bought another one and used Smart Switch to transfer everything directly onto it via WiFi. After checking everything had transferred correctly, I decided to clean up the old phone as it could still be used around the house.
I deleted various apps. When I got to the memo app, I just deleted all the memos.
A few minutes later, I went to the new phone and discovered all the memos there had also vanished. Apparently, I don't understand how sync'ing works.
I can't see any way to recover a back-in-time copy of the data.

Samsung Cloud (which I have not really used before) shows that "Memo" is synced, but the restore option doesn't offer any way to restore memos (it isn't listed under apps) nor documents of any kind.
I can't find any kind of "trash" location on the old phone.

I did this about an hour ago.
Have I lost all the memo data? Or is there a way to restore/undelete it if I am quick? (And if so, what do I need to do?)

Apparently, I'm not the first to discover this. I found a search result that seems very similar to my issue but following the link leads to a page that just says "This Content was Archived":

I can't find anything else on that forum that helps.
I have requested a data download from https://privacy.samsung.com on the off-chance that it contains the memo data.

although it has "Pinall" (=Scrapbook), "Samsung Notes" and "S-Note3" data, the "Samsung Cloud" data dump appears to contain nothing at all related to "Memo" :-(
